# (WP/S)ZipArchive progress/completion handler type in Swift

Tags: swift, ios9, handler

I'm trying to use the ZIP library [WPZipArchive](https://github.com/WPMedia/WPZipArchive/) which is a fork of [ZipArchive aka SZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) but I have a problem with the `unzipFileAtPath:toDestination:overwrite:password:progressHandler:completionHandler` (phew) function. 
[WPZipArchive.h#L35-L40](https://github.com/WPMedia/WPZipArchive/blob/master/WPZipArchive/WPZipArchive.h#L35-L40)

I'm programming in Swift and I have a problem with writing the handlers for the progress and completion handlers

e.g. how to create the `((String!, unz_file_info, Int, Int)->Void)!` handler?

Some attempts:

```
    WPZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(help, toDestination: temp, progressHandler: (entry:String!, info:unz_file_info, current:Int, total:Int) {
    }){ (path:String!, succeeded:Bool, error:NSError!) in
    }
```

with an error

> .../ViewController.swift:45:142: Cannot convert value of type '() ->
>   ()' to expected argument type '(entry: String!, info: unz_file_info,
>   current: Int, total: Int)' (aka '(entry:
>   ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional, info: unz_file_info_s, current:
>   Int, total: Int)')

this modification seems to work :)

```
    WPZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(help, toDestination: temp, progressHandler: {(entry:String!, info:unz_file_info, current:Int, total:Int) in


    }){ (path:String!, succeeded:Bool, error:NSError!) in

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the function name here but there are two handlers (closures) progress handler and the completion handler. I'm not sure which one calls the
    `((String!, unz_file_info, Int, Int)->Void)!`

```
func foo(completionHandler: (String!, unz_file_info, Int, Int)->Void){
    //do whatever you need to
    completionHandler("this is a string", <object of type unz_file_info>, 1, 2)
}
```

Alternatively if you are trying use the work with the data from the handler you would implement it

```
foo(completionHandler: { 
    (w:String!, x:unz_file_info, y:Int, z:Int) in

    print(w)
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(z)
})
```

You would put the other parameters first, for more information on closures see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/